# Prefix special characters in string with backslash

Tags: java, string

Is there easier way to prefix special characters with \ 
EX:

```
String result = subjectString.replaceAll("\\}", "\\\\\\}").replaceAll("\\{", "\\\\\\{").replaceAll("\\&", "\\\\\\&")
                .replaceAll("=", "\\\\=").replaceAll(",", "\\\\,")
                .replaceAll("\\@", "\\\\\\@")
                .replaceAll(">", "\\\\>").replaceAll("!", "\\\\!").replaceAll("\\+", "\\\\\\+");
```

Input:

```
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"\/>
```

Expected output:

```
<xsl\:with\-param name\=\"text\" select\=\"substring\-after(\$text\,\$replace)\"\/\>
```

Comment: What makes those character special? In other words, what's your need or goal?

Comment: Non alphanumeric characters. Language Java (Added)

Comment: Now your ASCII tag is confusing because Java doesn't use ASCII. Do you mean not one of the alphanumeric characters in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block? Or do you mean not a character with the general category Nd, Lu, Ll, Lo, or Lt per [Character class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER)?

Comment: If you're not using a regex, then don't use replaceAll. use replace().

Comment: @TomBlodget not one of the alphanumeric characters in the C0 Controls and Basic Latin block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with simple classes of characters, a regular expression can be a direct way of expressing the requirement:

```
"<xsl:with-param name=\"text\" select=\"substring-after($text,$replace)\" />"
    .replaceAll("([^0-9A-Za-z])", "\\\\$1")
```

`[]` gives the class of characters, which can include individual characters and ranges.

`[^]` negates the class of characters.

`()` creates a capture group, numbered by the open paren.

`$1` gives the value of the first capture.

`\\\\` is double-escaped "\"; once for a Java literal; once for Regex.

In words, replace each character that is not in the ranges 0-9, A-Z or a-z with that individual character prefixed by a backslash.

Comment: was looking for "$1 gives the value of the first capture." Thanks